# Model misconfigured. TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthroug

Tags: python, pipeline

I have a process that runs fine with no errors when in a jupyter notebook. But then I tried to build it in modules with different files and my `Pipeline` broke with an error that I have no idea what it is.

The following lines of code gives the expected result, just like the outputs of the jupyter notebook:

```
preprocessor = Preprocessor()
X_train = preprocessor.fit_transform(titanic_data)
y_train = titanic_labels
```

The problem arises when I try a RandomizedSearchCV:

```
svc_pipeline = Pipeline([("preprocessor", preprocessor), ("svc", SVC())])
rnd_search = RandomizedSearchCV(svc_pipeline,
                                param_distributions=param_distribs,
                                n_iter=10, cv=3,
                                scoring='accuracy',
                                verbose=2,
                                random_state=42)

rnd_search.fit(titanic_data, titanic_labels)
```

The last line raises the following error:

```
ValueError: 
All the 30 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/silviojr/.virtualenvs/handson/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/    model_selection/_validation.py", line 729, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/home/silviojr/.virtualenvs/handson/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/    base.py", line 1152, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/silviojr/.virtualenvs/handson/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/    pipeline.py", line 423, in fit
    Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
  File "/home/silviojr/.virtualenvs/handson/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/    pipeline.py", line 357, in _fit
    self._validate_steps()
  File "/home/silviojr/.virtualenvs/handson/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 241, in _validate_steps
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string
'passthrough' '<kaggle.titanic.preprocessing.Preprocessor object at 0x7f29c72589a0>'
 (type <class 'kaggle.titanic.preprocessing.Preprocessor'>) doesn't
```

And then it repeats the same thing again and again for the 30 fits. The same error message.

The `Preprocessor` is another .py file which I call as `from kaggle.titanic.preprocessing import Preprocessor` and it looks as (I am not reproducing the full code because it is too long but the 'important part' is here):

```
class Preprocessor:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit_transform(self, X):
        preprocessing_initial = self._initial_preprocessing()
        preprocessing_travel_category = self._travel_category_preprocessing()
        preprocessing_cat = self._categorical_preprocessing()
        preprocessing_drop_columns = self._drop_columns_preprocessing()

        # Combine all transformers in a pipeline
        preprocessor = make_pipeline(
            preprocessing_initial,
            preprocessing_travel_category,
            preprocessing_cat,
            preprocessing_drop_columns  # Add the transformer to drop columns at the end
        )

        return preprocessor.fit_transform(X)

    def _sum_name(self, function_transformer, feature_names_in):
        return ["total_relatives"]  # feature names out

    def _sum_relatives(self, X):
        X_copy = X.copy()
        X_copy['total_relatives'] = X_copy['SibSp'] + X_copy['Parch']
        return X_copy[['total_relatives']]

    def _total_relatives_pipeline(self):
    [...]
    def _initial_preprocessing(self):
        return ColumnTransformer([
                ("ord", self._ordinal_encoder(), ['Pclass']),
                ("age_processing", self._age_processor(), ['Pclass', 'Age']),
                ("num", self._fare_pipeline(), ['Fare']),
                ("total_relatives", self._total_relatives_pipeline(), ['SibSp', 'Parch'])],
                remainder='passthrough',
                verbose_feature_names_out=False
        )

    def _travel_category_preprocessing(self):
        return ColumnTransformer(
            [("travel_category", self._travel_category_pipeline(), ['total_relatives'])],
            remainder='passthrough',
            verbose_feature_names_out=False
        )

    def _categorical_preprocessing(self):
        return ColumnTransformer(
            [("cat", self._categorical_pipeline(), ['Sex', 'Embarked', 'traveling_category', 'age_interval'])],
            remainder='passthrough',
            verbose_feature_names_out=False
        )

    def _categorical_pipeline(self):
        return make_pipeline(
            SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent"),
            OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore", sparse_output=False)
        )

    def _drop_columns_preprocessing(self):
        return self._drop_columns()


class DropColumnsTransformer:
    def __init__(self, columns):
        self.columns = columns

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X.drop(columns=self.columns)

    def get_feature_names_out(self, input_features=None):
        return [col for col in input_features if col not in self.columns]
```

The thing is: I am learning and trying to make a more cleaner code putting classes, functions etc in other python files and calling then as modules. So I put the whole pipeline as a `Class` and I am trying to use it in the process. The whole thing works fine `X_train = preprocessor.fit_transform(titanic_data)` outputting exactly what was expected. But `rnd_search.fit(titanic_data, titanic_labels)` breaks.

Maybe I messed up when I wrote the `Preprocessor` Class, because when the whole thing was codes in a jupyter notebook's cells, it worked just fine. But I cannot figure out what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this since yesterday, maybe there are other solutions but I finally managed to fix the problem by replacing the first lines in `Class Preprocessor()` with the following:

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin

class Preprocessor(TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        preprocessing_initial = self._initial_preprocessing()
        preprocessing_travel_category = self._travel_category_preprocessing()
        preprocessing_cat = self._categorical_preprocessing()
        preprocessing_drop_columns = self._drop_columns_preprocessing()

        # Combine all transformers in a pipeline
        preprocessor = make_pipeline(
            preprocessing_initial,
            preprocessing_travel_category,
            preprocessing_cat,
            preprocessing_drop_columns  # Add the transformer to drop columns at the end
        )

        return preprocessor.fit_transform(X)
```

and it worked with no errors.